# CertificateError: hostname doesn't match

Tags: python, ssl, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm using a proxy (behind corporate firewall), to login to an https domain. The SSL handshake doesn't seem to be going well:

```
CertificateError: hostname 'ats.finra.org:443' doesn't match 'ats.finra.org'
```

I'm using Python 2.7.9 - Mechanize and I've gotten past all of the login, password, security questioon screens, but it is getting hung up on the certification.

Any help would be amazing. I've tried the monkeywrench found here: [Forcing Mechanize to use SSLv3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927339/forcing-mechanize-to-use-sslv3)

Doesn't work for my code though.

If you want the code file I'd be happy to send.

Comment: Can you most your `monkey-patch `code, maybe this can help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282797/feedparser-parse-ssl-certificate-verify-failed

Comment: It might be interesting to see the code you are using. It might be simply that you give "host:port" where instead only the hostname is expected, so that it uses the wrong name (i.e. "host:port" instead of "host") for verification of the hostname. I'm sure that it has nothing to do with SSLv3.

Comment: Hi @cmidi thank you for your response. I will try that code on Monday.

Comment: Hi, @SteffenUllrich, thanks for your response. I will paste the code on Monday, please circle back, I'm happy I got a response from someone on this.

Answer (score 27):

You can avoid this error by monkey patching ssl:

```
import ssl
ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True
```

Comment: where to add the code "ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True"

Answer (score 5):

In my case the certificate's DNS name was `::1` (for local testing purposes) and hostname verification failed with

```
ssl.CertificateError: hostname '::1' doesn't match '::1'
```

To fix it somewhat properly I monkey patched `ssl.match_hostname` with

```
import ssl                                                                                                                                                                                             
ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: hostname == cert['subjectAltName'][0][1]
```

Which actually checks if the hostnames match.

Answer (score 4):

This bug in ssl.math_hostname appears in v2.7.9 (it's not in 2.7.5), and has to do with not stripping out the hostname from the hostname:port syntax. The following rewrite of ssl.match_hostname fixes the bug. Put this before your mechanize code:

```
import functools, re, urlparse
import ssl

old_match_hostname = ssl.match_hostname

@functools.wraps(old_match_hostname)
def match_hostname_bugfix_ssl_py_2_7_9(cert, hostname):
    m = re.search(r':\d+$',hostname)  # hostname:port
    if m is not None:
        o = urlparse.urlparse('https://' + hostname)
        hostname = o.hostname
    old_match_hostname(cert, hostname)

ssl.match_hostname = match_hostname_bugfix_ssl_py_2_7_9
```

The following mechanize code should now work:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hang on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Nutscrape 1.0')]
# Use this proxy
br.set_proxies({"http": "localhost:3128", "https": "localhost:3128"})
r = br.open('https://www.duckduckgo.com:443/')
html = br.response().read()
# Examine the html response from a browser
f = open('foo.html','w')
f.write(html)
f.close()
```

Comment: Is the bug reported somewhere? Can we have a link please? Is it fixed in the newer versions?